# How are Canada Pension Plan payroll deductions paid by both employee and the company?

Tags: income-tax, canada, pension, employment, payroll-taxes

I am thinking on moving to Canada but I want to calculate what my salary would be after taxes. I am using the tax calculator at https://simpletax.ca/calculator but there's still one thing I can't wrap my head around:

In CPP, both the employer and the employee pay a part of the pre tax salary. For a salary over $57,400, what I expect to be my case, both the employer and the employee contribute 5.1% (see [here](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/payroll/payroll-deductions-contributions/canada-pension-plan-cpp/cpp-contribution-rates-maximums-exemptions.html)).

What I don't understand is whether the employer pays their 5.1% through their money, or through my salary? Can I trust $3609 per year the calculator gives me based on a $67,200 a year salary? (That number also includes EI.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CPP contributions will be deducted from your salary by your employer.

Your employer's contributions will be paid direct to the government. You will not see them, they will not show up on your payslip, and will have no effect on your final salary or tax situation.

Comment: Thanks. So I can trust the calculator result, right? It appears to be similar to my 5.1% and then the rest is probably just EI.

Comment: You will also have a deduction for EI as well as tax.